# Unity Behavior Designer get gameobject

Tags: unity

I am trying to create my own action in Behavior Designer. However i cannot seem to get the game object that designer is attached to. if i attempt to do:

```
protected Combatant enemyCombatantObject;

public override void OnAwake()
{
    enemyCombatantObject = GameObject.GetComponent<Combatant>();
    base.OnAwake();
}
```

It gives me an error:

> the property or indexer 'Task.GameObject' cannot be used in this
>   context because it lacks the get accessor

Can anyone tell me how to get the `GameObject` that the script is attached to?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Behavior Designer" in Unity. I think you are just talking about writing script code. Or is that some plugin you've downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gameObject.GetComponent<Combatant>();`. Note the small `g`. `gameObject` is the object the script is attached to.

`GameObject` is the class of all game objects. You can use `GameObject` to call methods which aren't specific to any particular game object ("static methods"), like `GameObject.CreatePrimitive` or `GameObject.Find`. You also need to use `GameObject` when you want to declare a variable which holds a reference to a game object.